Applying the heat semigroup to a tempered distribution
Let $e^{t\Delta}$ be the heat semigroup. Classically, $e^{t\Delta}u$ is the solution to the heat equation at time $t$ with initial condition $u$. In the book Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations by Bahouri, Chemin, and Danchin they extend this to $u$ being a tempered distribution whose Fourier transform is supported in an annulus. In fact, they give the following bound for $u \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R^n}$):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an annulus. Positive constants $c$ and $C$ exist such that for any $p \in [1, \infty]$ and any couple $(t, \lambda)$ of positive real numbers, we have $$\text{Supp } \hat{u} \subset\lambda \mathcal{C} \implies \|e^{t\Delta}u\|_{L^p} \leq Ce^{-ct\lambda^2}\|u\|_{L^p}.$$

In their proof they state the following:
$$e^{t\Delta}u = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big(\phi(\xi)e^{t|\xi|^2}\hat{u}(\xi)\Big) \tag{1}$$
where $\phi$ is a smooth function defined on $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\}$ and which is equal to 1 on $\mathcal{C}$.

What justifies the right-hand side of (1) as being the solution to the heat equation and why is $\phi$ required here?
How can one interpret the heat semigroup applied to a distribution? Is it a time-dependent weak solution where the time dependence is strong? After all, the heat kernel is itself a distribution so we are taking a convolution of two distributions. On the physical side, we are looking at the evolution of a heat distribution where the initial distribution may not even be defined pointwise so how can we interpret this?
The heat semigroup has a smoothening property when acting on functions. Is there anything similar when it acts on distributions?

